# How does pytest deal with fixtures calling other fixtures?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I have two pytest fixtures, `client` and `app`. `client` calls `app`.

The test function `test_register` has arguments `client` and `app` and hence calls both fixtures.

My question is if the instance of `app` used in test_register is always going to be the one that `client` called, and if this is how pytest works in general (the assertion in test_register passes, so it is true in this case) .

In other words, does pytest generate unrelated instances for each argument in a test function that calls a fixture or does it call the fixtures and the instances returned also reference each other?

Here's the code:

```
@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app({
        'TESTING': True,
    })

    yield app


@pytest.fixture
def client(app):
    return app.test_client()



def test_register(client, app):
    assert client.application is app
```

Comment: In the context of your question, fixtures are just functions that will called for you before the test starts, so you don't have to do it yourself and can start using their result immediately. Their result is stored for the time the test "lives" (`function` scope). I guess what you are afraid of is that is that `app()` will be called twice, once in `client()`, then again in `test_register()`, but that's not how it works. `app` will be called once when first requested, the reference of its result will be stored and passed to `client()` and `test_register()`, so you can rely on that.

Comment: However, be aware that if you would have another test, e.g. `def test_unregister(app)`, then the `app` instances in both tests would be different - this is regulated by the `scope` setting in fixture. By default, the `scope` is set to `function`, so the fixtures are called again before different tests; if you set the `scope` to `session`, then the fixture will be called once per test run and all test functions will get the same `app` instance.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was asking! I was wondering if `app` will be called twice, once by `client` and once by `test_register` and if there will be two different instances of it. Is there a part of `pytest` documentation clarifying this? I looked into it but couldn't find anything.

Comment: I don't know whether this is stated explicitly somewhere in the docs, but passing fixtures as test arguments is an implementation of depency injection, and this is how DI usually works (although not a must). Think about a fixture that should run some heavy-lifting calculation and return the result or open and return a DB connection, if they are duplicated and not reused, that would be a disaster!

Answer (score 1):

All fixtures have a scope, the implicit scope being `function` but there's also `class`, `module` and `session` scopes.  Within each scope there will only ever be one instance created of a fixture.

So in your example both `app` and `client` are using the function-scope.  When executing `test_register` it enters the function-scope of this test and creates the fixture intances.  Hence both `test_register` and `client` get the same instance of `app`.

See [the docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session) for more details on how this all works.